# Does Ryanair serve alcohol on short flights (e.g. Dublin-London)?

Tags: air-travel, london, ryanair, dublin

I'm flying from Dublin to London with Ryanair.

I'm just wondering if anyone knows whether or not Ryanair will be serving alcohol on such a short flight?

Comment: You think an Irish airline isn't gonna sell booze? Especially bearing in mind it's one that tries to sell you travel insurance, luggage, rent-a-car's, bus tickets, keyrings, a cat in a hat, etc.. when you book; and wants to [charge you to use the toilets](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/article-1263905/Ryanair-toilet-charges-phased-in.html)! Though I do wonder what a drunkard with no money for the toilet, would do; after being plied with Ryainair's €10 miniature whiskey + coke's...

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Ryanair's proposal to charge for the toilets was never implemented, and few people believe it was ever intended seriously.  The airline is notorious for announcing things like this for the publicity and then backing away.  Like their recent [proposal to fly to North America](http://www.economist.com/blogs/gulliver/2015/03/ryanair-0).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They do sell alcoholic beverages:

http://www.ryanair.com/en/questions/what-snacks-and-drinks-are-available-onboard/

Comment: And it's a short 1h20min flight. Economically speaking it would be better to drink before and after the flight, not during it. Would save you some Euros (or pounds)!

Comment: @pnuts Oh yeah, I know it's going to ridiculously overpriced, but it's a bit of a ritual.

Comment: @Daft, this might be a case of... http://i.qkme.me/3q497c.jpg

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you can, legally, bring 100ml bottles of liquid on board. In fact, you can bring 10 100ml bottles of liquid on board... Save the little bottles you buy!

Comment: @MastaBaba hahaha... very clever!!

Comment: @pnuts hhhmmm... now I feel as if it's a challenge!

Comment: Enlist your neighbours and have them ask for drinks too (when the drinks are free).

Answer (score 6):

It's a long time I haven't flown with them but I would be surprised if they would not. Their [regular flight menu obviously includes alcoholic drinks](http://www.ryanair.com/en/questions/what-snacks-and-drinks-are-available-onboard/) and I could not find any mention of any restriction for short flights anywhere.

I can't see a reason why they would specifically exclude alcohol either. Unlike full-service airlines, who could welcome an excuse to save a bit of money, Ryanair actually stands to profit from the drinks they serve, since you have to pay for them. So if they have the time for any on-board service, I would expect it to include alcohol.

Answer (score 5):

I regularly fly short haul with ryanair and have never been on a flight where alcohol wasn't sold.